# How to mount a ntfs disk in the text mode(from command line)?

Tags: command-line, mount

In the gui, mode to mount a disk , I just click the name of the drive in the menu "place", and the disk gets mounted. However, can I mount that drive easily in the text mode (from terminal or command line) just using a command?

Answer (score 4):

You can mount the drive from command line easily even without creating a folder in `/media` as other question suggests.

- Open a terminal
- Type `udisks --mount /dev/sda2`

#### The result?

Your `/dev/sda2` will be mounted in the `/media/label`, where `label` refers to the name of label of the partition. For example, my `/dev/sda2` is labeled as `Main`, and when i do the command, "/dev/sda2" will be mounted on `/media/Main`.

#### How do i know, My Drive "Drivename"'s `sdaX` number ?

- You can execute `sudo blkid` command in a terminal to know, which sdaX you have to input.

  Example: My example run returns this:

```
anwar@edubuntu-lenovo:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="01CD4993623F05D0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Main" UUID="A80C1BD70C1B9F7E" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Work" UUID="01CCB271A80A07E0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Free" UUID="DE53-CB6B" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="364126ac-01c9-4dd2-ab19-eecc733a9640" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="b1537dfc-e918-4fea-9a99-44a034e57429" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="01CD49906DD38770" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda9: LABEL="Precise-New" UUID="7c934266-dfcb-45de-879b-e3ceafcd0862" TYPE="ext4"
```

So i know that, if I wanted to mount "Work", I have to use `sda3`.

#### If the partition has no label:

If your partition has no label, it will be mounted in `/media/UUID`, where `UUID` refers to the UUID of the partition.
For example: If i mount my `/dev/sda8`, which does not have a Label, it will be mounted in `/media/01CD49906DD38770` Folder.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a dir (preferably in `/media`), for example `win`. You can do it with `sudo mkdir /media/win`.

After that you can use the `sudo ntfs-3g /dev/device /media/win` command. You have to replace the device with the correct device identifier (sdb2 for example means the second partition of the second storage device in your computer).

If everything went OK, `/media/win` will contain that NTFS partition.

Comment: One thing to note though, if this does not work, you can possibly replace the `sudo ntfs-3g /dev/device /media/win` command with `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/device /media/win` (replacing `device` with the correct device identifier as is explained in Iradrian's post).

Comment: How to get the device id? Is there a command to do this?

Comment: @Jinx, as I wrote down earlier, the devices get an automated name. If you are unsure which is your device, you can run the `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` command for example, so you can filter whether it has your NTFS partition or not.